# WS2812b LEDs intermittently do not respond to data signal

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, led-strip, ws2812b

I have wired up permanent holiday LEDs on the front of my home, using a 5V 60A power supply and several strips of WS2812b's (generic Neopixels), controlled by a Wemos D1 mini.

The Wemos is powered via the 5V pin, and I'm using a logic level shifter to bring the 3V ESP8266 data output up to 5V for the pixels.  I have a 330 ohm resistor at the end of the data line closest to the pixels and a 1000 uf capacitor across the power leads, per the Adafruit best practices guide for Neopixels (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/best-practices).

The power supply is switched by a Sonoff Basic, so the Sonoff basically acts as a "main" for both the LEDs and the Wemos.

However, when I turn on the Sonoff and the whole system powers up, I occasionally experience one or a few of these:

- Randomly colored LEDs down the strip
- Only the first few LEDs in the strip running the sequences I've coded
- Nothing but the first LED lit at a random color

Sometimes, it powers up and works great.

However, all works fine every time if I put a manual switch on the 5V line of the Neopixels, power up the system via the Sonoff (thus powering only the Wemos), then flip the manual switch to on shortly *after* the Wemos is powered up.

I understand that interference due to a floating data line is to be expected...

Any ideas what might be causing this?  I'd love to just be able to power on and off the whole thing with the Sonoff and not have to worry about the manual switch.

Could the data line be floating and the pixels somehow start up in a strange state such that they won't respond after the Wemos runs its setup code and initializes the LEDs?

I'm at a loss as to what to try next.  I built a similar setup for my neighbor, minus the Sonoff (he just manually plugs it in), the data line resistor, and some slightly different code, and his worked consistently throughout the holidays.

Any ideas on what to try next would be welcome!

**EDIT:** Every single time I power the setup in the evenings, it works great.  But when I try to power it up during the day, it usually (90% of the time) doesn't work.  I wanted to wait a few days to test this to be sure - and it's been perfectly consistent.  I don't change anything with the circuit between the morning and the evening either.  This is what makes it so hard to debug!

Comment: If the noise goes away when you earth ground yourself and touch the 0Vdc then you have an EMI SMPS issue.  affecting data integrity from COmmon mode noise and antenna effects of LEDstrip with high switched currents V=LdI/dt. So it is either conducted noise or radiated noise.

Comment: So would you recommend anything to reduce the noise? Ferrite beads? A capacitor?

Comment: Did you do my test. You mist tell me if the interference is radiated if that works or no then it is conducted ground noise.

Comment: Well, at the moment it's working without touching anything. It could be unrelated, but it seems to work more often in the evenings and almost never works in the mornings. Temperature related maybe? Perhaps just a coincidence. This morning it didn't work, but this evening after work it did.  I'll try again tomorrow morning and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, so as expected, it was inconsistent this morning. The initial power up was fine. I waited about 15 minutes, tried again, and only the first 30 LEDs responded, with a few random colors down the rest of the strips. I put my finger on the PSU's 0Vdc terminal and stood barefoot on my concrete garage floor, powered up the Sonoff, and the LEDs still misbehaved.  So perhaps it's radiated noise? Any thoughts and suggestions?

Comment: I was thinking a 0 ohm wire to the electrical ground in a socket or PC power, rather than 10k from feet to concrete, but good try. If this doesn't fix, that reduces the radiated noise, it must be conducted noise or crosstalk from cable proximity and length. Got any photos?

Comment: Is it the power ON Reset failing?  Is there a manual reset?

Comment: I'm happy to try a wire from 0vdc to socket ground. It's only 3 screws away on the PSU's terminal block.  Let me get you a photo too.

Comment: Here's a photo: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvgokyyfeekl9k8/_CISwic-.jpg?dl=0

Comment: No luck with the wire from 0Vdc to socket ground.

Comment: 150 Ohm series with 0.1uF on PCB rails?   thats what is in datasheet https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf for Vcc

Comment: Do you have any other thoughts that might be able to point me in the right direction?  For some reason, the system almost *always* works correctly in the evenings and early mornings, but when powered on during the day, it completely misbehaves.

Comment: Measure DC voltages , AC noise, Data signal, change power source, change location